# Passing variable to regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression

```
var p = /\bj[^\b]*?\b/gi;
```

I need to make the 'j' a variable value, but when i do the following;-

```
var p = new RegExp('\\b'+'${0}'+'[^\\b]*?\\b', 'gi');
```

I get error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\b${0}[^\b]*?\b/: Nothing to repeat
```

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `[^\b]` doesn't do what you probably think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I should have been more clear, the value '{0}' is a token that will be replaced and not a variable. The error was occurring because '{' and '}' are special characters in regular expressions.

So changing the token pattern fixed the problem

```
var p = new RegExp('\\b'+'%text%'+'[^\\b]*?\\b', 'gi');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following:

```
var p = new RegExp('\\b'+${0}+'[^\\b]*?\\b', 'gi');
```

With the quotes around `${0}` you are just constructing a string with those characters, instead of inserting the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a variable within quotation marks as you have done with `'${0}'` is going to cause that to be treated as a string.  If you remove the quotation marks from around it then it will be treated as a variable.